How to find deprecated APIs
My organization is a startup that has a microservice architecture (Python). There are several services that expose some endpoints. The problem is that, as the startup grew, many things were dynamic, code changed and people came and went... and we are certain for a fact that there's more than a few endpoints that aren't used anymore and we want to find what those are and delete them. We're just not sure what the approach to such a problem should be, because we don't want to break things... but on the other hand, the code is becoming bloated and filled with garbage...
Any known solution or tools for such a problem?

When we encountered such situation on my project, we simply asked the front-end engineers to create a list of API's that are being used by front-end application.
The problem is that you could have many services and only few could have front-end. Also, you didn't specify if the clients of your application are using the API-s you provide, in this specific case this could be harder to just delete something.
Off the top of my head, every service if deployed should have logs written by your webserver (nginx,apache,etc). There should be None logs for routes that are not used internally.
If you have a monitoring system you could've just added some business metric using Prometheus that would export call count or somehow indicate that a route is not used. It's hard to answer what to do because there's lack of information about things you do and the size of these things. It's easy to add few business metrics to a few small services, but if the codebase is huge you should choose another solution.
Your application should run behind something and for many web servers there are in-built Prometheus exporters that would simplify this for you. If that is not a case you could write your own exporter
